# 'fewer' vs 'less' with plural noun phrases

Tags: word-choice

The following (cited at [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/505/50720)) from the *Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* still confuses me. I've recast the formatting for readability and discuss only [i] to [iii]; I think I understand the other examples.

> The relation between *less* and *fewer* is fairly complex. In non-count singulars only *less* is possible:
>   *Kim has less  <s>fewer</s>  money than Pat.* In plural NPs we have: 
>   [17]
>   i. She left less than ten minutes ago.
>   ii. Less/Fewer than thirty of the students had voted.
>   iii. He made no less/fewer than fifteen mistakes.
>
> Both [i] and [ii] have *than* + numeral. In [i] 'ten minutes' expresses an amount of time rather than `a number of individuated units`, and in such cases **fewer** is virtually impossible—just as **few** would be `in a comparison of equality`: She left as little <s>few</s> as ten minutes ago.* Similarly with *We paid less than thirty dollars for it; She’s less than forty years old; We were going at less than ten miles an hour.*

1. Why are **fewer** and **few** wrong? 'ten minutes' DOES express `a number of individuated units`, because it expresses an increment of ten minutes, rather than minutes themselves. You can certainly count intervals of 10 minutes, so **fewer** should be used?

2. Why is **few** impossible `in a comparison of equality`? The above doesn't appear to explain.

> In [ii] we are concerned with countable individuals and *little* cannot be used in a comparison of equality (<s>as little as thirty of the students</s>); nevertheless, for inequality **less** is more common than **fewer** in this construction. The same applies with percentages: *Less/Fewer than 30% of the students had voted.*
>
> Construction [iii] has the comparative form following *no*: though the interpretation is count plural, *less* is here again more common than *fewer*.

3. The above implies that only **few** is truly right for [ii] and fewer for [iii],
so  why's **less** 'more common' in both cases?

Comment: *Few* does not specify quantity but cardinality.

Answer (score 1):

## Less than ten minutes

In this example, *time* is being treated as a fluid quantity, like water.  "I have less water" - "I have less time."

The fact that we measure it using individual units (minutes) doesn't matter.

"I have ten litres of water".  "I have twenty litres of water." "I have less water than you do!  I have less than twenty litres of water."

"I did it in ten minutes." "I did it in twenty minutes." "I took less time than you did!  I took less than twenty minutes to do it."

## "Less" when it should be "fewer"

The issue here is that in almost every case where "fewer than" is correct, "less than" is *almost* correct.  If you use "less than" when you were supposed to use "fewer than", you'll still be understood 99% of the time.

Because of this almost-correctness of "less than", some people use less in most/all cases.  They don't bother keeping track of when to use which one - they just use "less than" everywhere.

It's a colloquialism.  If you do it in front of a teacher, the teacher will probably correct you.  But it is common, even among native speakers.